Is there an alternative device driver for Samsung Xpresss M2020?
After convincing my wife to switch to (L)Ubuntu I have become quite frustrated trying to get her perfectly good Samsung Xpress M2020 printer to work. HP apparently no longer hosts the driver for that printer so I am wondering if anyone has found an alternative print driver. I have searched a number of databases but am drawing a blank. The printer worked well under WIndows 10 but support for that is going away and I have convinced my wife that LIinux is much more secure anyway.

"HP apparently no longer hosts the driver for that printer " what do you mean by that?  samsung printer is hp?! Samsung uses cups so I would assume it should just work.  That printer worked in 2020 it seems https://www.linux.org/threads/samsung-m2020-missing-printer-driver-debian-11-solved.38434/ but do check the comment about  missing a dependecy

I simply meant that I cannnot fond a driver specific for the Xpress M02020 printer in the HP repository of rht Samsun repository. I am using CUPS to manage the driver installation. I'm still looking.

Got it working! YOur hint to go to linux.org/thresds... pointed me to a site that had a driver packege. I downloaded that and extra cted to my local directory. I used CUPS to point to the PPD file for the M2020. Viola! THanks so much. I just couldn't find the repository for the driver that I needed.

No problem. Just make a backup of the tar file ;-)

oh and please make an answer so you can accept it !
